# How to zip together lists of unequal length into a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three lists.

```
import pandas as pd

author = ['mccoy.robert']
coauthors = [
    'hola.lubica', 'kundu.subiman', 'ntantu.ibula', 
    'fletcher.peter', 'jain.tanvi', 'jindal.varun', 'bankston.paul',
    'di-maio.giuseppe', 'dickman.raymond-f-jun', 'holy.dusan',
    'slover.rebecca', 'curtis.douglas-w', 'duvall.paul-f', 'fogelgren.j-r',
    'hammer.s-t', 'haworth.r-c', 'lutzer.david-j', 'okuyama.akihiro', 
    'pelant.jan', 'porter.jack-ray', 'raha.asit-baran', 'rubin.leonard-roy',
    'santoro.grazia', 'smith.jerome-c', 'todd.aaron-r'
]
frequency = [
    '10', '8', '6', '5', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', 
    '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'
]
```

I'd like to make these lists into a dataframe in which each row is the author paired with each coauthor and the frequency of collaborations.  Basically if I could zip these three lists together, with the list 'author' replicated over and over in each row, this would be great.

This seems like a fairly simple pandas task... but I'd love some help on it!

Comment: Can you include a small sample of your desired output?

Comment: Please fix your code so it can be copy-pasted into a terminal. There are extra line breaks there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with nested `for` loop, looping over the authors and the zipped coauthors and frequencies. Like so:

```
authors = ['mccoy.robert']
coauthors = [
    'hola.lubica', 'kundu.subiman', 'ntantu.ibula', 
    'fletcher.peter', 'jain.tanvi', 'jindal.varun', 'bankston.paul',
    'di-maio.giuseppe', 'dickman.raymond-f-jun', 'holy.dusan',
    'slover.rebecca', 'curtis.douglas-w', 'duvall.paul-f', 'fogelgren.j-r',
    'hammer.s-t', 'haworth.r-c', 'lutzer.david-j', 'okuyama.akihiro', 
    'pelant.jan', 'porter.jack-ray', 'raha.asit-baran', 'rubin.leonard-roy',
    'santoro.grazia', 'smith.jerome-c', 'todd.aaron-r'
]
frequencies = [
    '10', '8', '6', '5', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', 
    '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'
]

combined = []

for author in authors:
    for coauthor, frequency in zip(coauthors, frequencies):
        combined.append((author, coauthor, frequency))
```

With Output:

```
[
    ('mccoy.robert', 'hola.lubica', '10'), ('mccoy.robert', 'kundu.subiman', '8'), ('mccoy.robert', 'ntantu.ibula', '6'),
    ('mccoy.robert', 'fletcher.peter', '5'), ('mccoy.robert', 'jain.tanvi', '3'), ('mccoy.robert', 'jindal.varun', '3'),
    ('mccoy.robert', 'bankston.paul', '2'), ('mccoy.robert', 'di-maio.giuseppe', '2'), ('mccoy.robert', 'dickman.raymond-f-jun', '2'),
    ('mccoy.robert', 'holy.dusan', '2'), ('mccoy.robert', 'slover.rebecca', '2'), ('mccoy.robert', 'curtis.douglas-w', '1'),
    ('mccoy.robert', 'duvall.paul-f', '1'), ('mccoy.robert', 'fogelgren.j-r', '1'), ('mccoy.robert', 'hammer.s-t', '1'),
    ('mccoy.robert', 'haworth.r-c', '1'), ('mccoy.robert', 'lutzer.david-j', '1'), ('mccoy.robert', 'okuyama.akihiro', '1'),
    ('mccoy.robert', 'pelant.jan', '1'), ('mccoy.robert', 'porter.jack-ray', '1'), ('mccoy.robert', 'raha.asit-baran', '1'),
    ('mccoy.robert', 'rubin.leonard-roy', '1'), ('mccoy.robert', 'santoro.grazia', '1'), ('mccoy.robert', 'smith.jerome-c', '1'),
    ('mccoy.robert', 'todd.aaron-r', '1')
]
```